# Why am I missing Spring Actuator 2 endpoints in CloudFoundry, while the the same setup works locally?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator

I'm deploying an application on SAP Cloud Foundry, with Spring Actuator 2.0 embedded but the endpoints are not showing up as expected. Only the default ones (health, info) are enabled.

The very same setup works locally and all desired endpoints are available. I'm even trying to explicitly enable them, even though documentation says they are already enabled by default.

There's no information on CF logs about any issues with the Actuator.

Here's my Actuator dependency on pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And here's my application.yml containing the Actuator setup, including explicit enablement of the endpoints.

```
management:
  endpoint:
    beans:
      enabled: true
    caches:
      enabled: true
    env:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
    loggers:
      enabled: true
    metrics:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: beans, caches, env, health, info, loggers, metrics
```

Am I missing something? Couldn't find any hard restrictions about this on SAP CF as well.

Comment: How are you running locally? What is your path when you `cf push`? Have you tried running `mvn clean package` or similar for gradle and then `cf push` again?

Comment: Locally, I'm just running using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin (no CF Local for now). As for the push, I'm pointing to the .war file, built by Maven. (mvn clean package -Denv=cf). BTW, the "cf" profile only differs in the way the app creates the DataSource bean, nothing more.

Comment: My only thought that could account for what you're seeing is that your WAR file was out of date. When you run `mvn spring-boot:run`, it's not building a WAR file. If you ran that a bunch and made changes, you'd need to remember to `mvn package` or something that does rebuild the WAR before your `cf push`.

Comment: Oh, one other thought. Env variables. You can configure a great deal of Spring Boot with just env variables. Perhaps you had one set that impacted Actuator? Env variables in CF are sticky on the server side. Even if you removed it from your manifest.yml, it would still be set server side. You also mentioned recreating the application, which would give you a fresh app in CF with no env variables. Kind of fits the circumstances, but just a wild guess.

Comment: For any reason, the application was not updating properly on CF. It happened one more time after this and I had to manually restart it to apply the changes. Right now I'm checking why it might be getting stuck. But still, restarting (or even recreating the app) seems to fix it. Thanks for  your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to re-create the application and now it seems to work.

I'm really not sure why a simple redeployment was not working and there was nothing about it in the logs.

The endpoints are there now and for reference, I'm using the same configuration above (I might try removing all the "enable" flags, though).

Comment: If you use IntelliJ and Maven, and you refactored your code (e.g. changed package names, moved files, renamed files...) something IntelliJ doesn't "see" the updated and keeps using the old versions. I had this issue whereIntelliJ persistenly kept using an application.properties that was deleted! Running a Maven Clean on the project (which basically deletes the target folder) fixed this issue for me, and all new settings/files were properly recognized.

Comment: It's good to know that but unfortunately, not the case right now as we're using STS for development and building the deployable version outside the editor.